# Multiple time series in stacked column chart

Tags: highcharts

Currently I'm playing around with the "stacked and grouped column" [example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-stacked-and-grouped/). There you visualize one data series within a stacked and grouped column chart.
From a theoretical point of view here you have one information (Number of fruits) grouped by three aspects (fruit (x-axis), person (stack) and gender (group)).

I'm wondering if (and how) it's possible to visualize an additional data series as grouping aspect instead of the gender.
I tried this (jsfiddle dot net/u1asm65s/) and added another data series representing figures for the very same persons in the first data series. But unfortunately, HIghcharts doesn't match the `name`s of both data series. Thus the persons are duplicated in the resulting column chart.

This is what I currently have:
[image]

And this is what I want to achieve:
[image]

I used GIMP, so it's not a real chart ;)

Do you have any idea?

Thanks in advance
Newlukai

PS: Sorry for not embedding images, but I'm not allowed to embed images.

Comment: You're explicitly telling the chart to make multiple series with the same name. I am not at all clear what your desired result is. can you clarify? Link to an imgur.com image if you need to. I am guessing that what you want to do will not be a problem, and will just require properly formatting the series and data, but need more info

Comment: I applied some GIMP magic and tried to make clear what I want to do.

Answer (score 2):

So basically, you can think of the desired effect as: I have an additional series which is linked (somehow) to another. Then you need to list what should be linked and set the options properly.

First, you want to connect visibility of the linked series and their appearance in the legend. It can be achieved via series.linkedTo property.

```
    {
        name: 'John-eaten',
        id: 'john',
        data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2],
        stack: 'eaten'
    },...,{
        name: 'John-bought',
        linkedTo: 'john',
        data: [6, 4, 5, 8, 3],
                    stack: 'bought'
    },
```

So now, there are two series which are coupled together.
http://jsfiddle.net/u1asm65s/2/

Second, the color - set the same color for the linked series. http://jsfiddle.net/u1asm65s/3/

Third, tooltip, legend, data labels - this can be adjusted easily with formatter callbacks. http://jsfiddle.net/u1asm65s/4/

Comment: Thanks @morganfree. I also thought about using linkage, coloring and formatting the tooltip (http://jsfiddle.net/n0q01yy5/): But I'm not sure if it's the "right" way. However, it also seems to be the only way to get the result I wanted.